# react - map two fields to option value?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following example data:

```
# Json file
[
{"symbol": "ABC", "name": "Ace to The Base Camp", "country": "United States", "industry": "Electrical Products"}, 
{"symbol": "BAC", "name": "BLAST OFF", "country": "United States", "industry": "Electrical Products"}
]
```

Currently I am using `map` to create `option` and letting user search and pick the correct `symbol` based on `symbol` alone.

Using this:

```
<input name="ticker" id="ticker" list="stockSelection" onChange={this.onChange} value={ticker} className="form-control text-center" />
     <datalist id="stockSelection">
              {this.state.country === "United States of America"
                    ? USDATA.map(({symbol}) => <option value={symbol}/>)
                    : INDIADATA.map(({symbol}) => <option value={symbol}/>)}
     </datalist>
```

I want to show the `name`(from json file) in the search field, making it searchable as well.

Example of what I mean:

Currently user types "Ab" and the dropdown list shows ABC as the symbol. Doesn't show the name of ABC i.e. "Ace to The Base Camp". I want the name to be shown and searchable. onSelect I just want the symbol.

Trying to figure it out but failing.

Answer (score 1):

you can extract the `name` out, like `symbol`.
in this way the name which is `"Ace to The Base Camp"` will shown to the user and value `ABC` will return as a value of option tag.

normally i do something like this:

```
<datalist id="stockSelection">
              {this.state.country === "United States of America"
                    ? USDATA.map(({symbol, name}) => <option key={symbol} value={symbol}>{name}</option>)
                    : INDIADATA.map(({symbol, name}) => <option key={symbol} value={symbol}>{name}</option>)}
     </datalist>
```

for second part of question:

when you searching you basically filtering the result.
so you can do like this:

```
 const [input, setInput] = useState();

 // search input handler 
 const handleChange = (e) => {
     setInput(e.target.value)
 };

 // in your component
    <select>
         {myList.filter(item => input.indexOf(item.symbol) >= 0 || input.indexOf(item.name) >= 0)
         .map(item => <option key={item.symbol} value={item.symbol}>{item.name}</option>)}
    </select>
```

Comment: I want to show both the name and symbol to the user, i.e. `symbol      name` to the user, and they should be able to search with both the name and symbol. I tried the solution and am trying to figure out how exactly to change it to show both of the values and for them to be searchable.